# How can I escape '<' and '>' dynamically in PHP?

Tags: php, html

For example, I have a string with value "CT.< S >" but in my HTML the  is treated as a tag when echoed. Is there a function I can use to echo "CT. \< S\>" (for example) instead so that the HTML isn't treated as a tag?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[`htmlspecialchars`](http://php.net/htmlspecialchars) and [`htmlentities`](http://php.net/htmlentities) both do this.